# what is the use of "either" type constructor in hakell

Tags: haskell

While studying haskell's type system, I came across the type constructor called "Either". One use case was the code below

```hs
import qualified Data.Map as Map  

data LockerState = Taken | Free deriving (Show, Eq)  
type Code = String  
type LockerMap = Map.Map Int (LockerState, Code)  


lockerLookup :: Int -> LockerMap -> Either String Code  
lockerLookup lockerNumber map =   
    case Map.lookup lockerNumber map of   
        Nothing            -> Left $ "Locker number " 
                                ++ show lockerNumber ++ " doesn't exist!"  
        Just (state, code) -> if state /= Taken   
                                then Right code  
                                else Left $ "Locker " ++ show lockerNumber 
                                       ++ " is already taken!"  


lockers :: LockerMap  
lockers = Map.fromList   
    [(100,(Taken,"ZD39I"))  
    ,(101,(Free,"JAH3I"))  
    ,(103,(Free,"IQSA9"))  
    ,(105,(Free,"QOTSA"))  
    ,(109,(Taken,"893JJ"))  
    ,(110,(Taken,"99292"))  
    ]
```

with an example function call:

```
> lockerLookup 101 lockers
```

I wonder why not just remove `Left` and `Right` value constructors. The code will still work fine while still being able to print out values we want.

Comment: I do not see any use of `Either` here? Only of `Maybe`.

Comment: I have made an edit and added Left and Right.

Comment: If you return `String` instead of `Either String Code` then how will the caller know if the lockerLookup was successful? Maybe good enough if you are only printing that String and let a human deal with the output, but if there is any logic supposed to happen, you need do know if it was "right" or "left".

Comment: @Thilo Can I think of "Either" as a way to give meanings to what the output of the string is? if Left : error, Right: fine

Comment: @youngseokjeon: this is indeed a popular use case. Another one is just a "tagged union".

Comment: You’re just about to stumble across the fact that `Either String String` (a + a) is equivalent to `(Bool, String)` (2 × a) in the algebra of Algebraic Data Types—in both cases, there’s a string tagged with whether it indicates an error or success

Answer (score 8):

`Either` is a [*tagged union* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). It means it can take values from (in this case) two types. If `Code` is for example *not* a string, your function will need some sort of sum type. How will it otherwise communicate a `Code` or a `String`? `Either` is thus for example used in a list that can contain `Int`s and `String`s: `[Either Int String]`.

`Either` is frequently used to encapsulate a computation that could fail. The `Left` constructor then stores an error message/exception parameters, whereas the `Right` data constructor stores the result of a successful computation.

This logic is encoded in the [`instance Monad Either` [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Either.html#line-155), indeed:

> ```
> instance Monad (Either e) where
>     Left  l >>= _ = Left l
>     Right r >>= k = k r
> ```

So here we can define a computation like:

```
some_computation :: Val1 -> Either Err Val4
some_computation v1 = do
    v2 <- some_computation_that_can_fail1 v1
    v3 <- some_computation_that_can_fail1 v2
    some_computation_that_can_fail v2 v3
```

In this hypothetical example, the functions have as type `some_computation_that_can_fail1 :: Val1 -> Either Err Val2`, `some_computation_that_can_fail2 :: Val2 -> Either Err Val3` and `some_computation_that_can_fail1 :: Val2 -> Val3 -> Either Err Val4`.

Here if `some_computation_that_can_fail1 v1` returns a `Left err`, then the `some_computation v1` will return that `Left err`. If on the other hand, it returns a `Right result`, then `v2` will access that result, and thus you can further process the `result` in the `some_computation_that_can_fail2 v2`, and so on.